# How to retrieve TcxDBLookupComboBox selected value?

Tags: delphi, dataset, devexpress

I have a DevExpress TcxDBLookupComboBox v12.1.5 with:

DataBinding.Datafile -> integer field
DataBinding.DataSource -> dbisam table

DropDownListStyle -> lsEditList

ImmediatePost -> true

ListFieldIndex -> 1
ListFieldNames -> itemcode; itemname

Item Code is a integer field, that I want to be retrieved to the connected dataset. However I want to search on the drop down list by the item's name

That is working, due the ListFieldINdex, however when I select the item on the drop down list it retrieve the itemcode and display the itemname on the edit box. That is not what I need.

I know I can change the DisplayValue using the OnValidate Event of the component, however I cant find how to retrieve the selected itemcode from the dropdownlist. Using the connected dataset field always return 0. ImmediatePost is not changing anything on the field. I am retrieving fields from the dataset using the FieldByName property.

How can i get the itemcode seleted to pass to the DisplayValue on the OnValidate?

Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE:

I am now using the SyncMode, and by that I can easily get the itemcode from the record selected.

However I could not make the control work the way I need:

- to enter the itemcode directly for direct access
- to open the lookup for itemname search
- display the ItemCode when the I find the search by itemname and the lookup list get closed

Comment: There is a SynchMode property in Properties|ListOptions which you could set to True.  This will scroll the cursor when you select the item in the dropdown which should give you direct access to the Item Code field.  So after selecting you can use DataSet.FieldByName('item_code').AsInteger to retrieve or similar.  What is your KeyFieldNames set to? You could also possibly read dbLookupComboBox.EditValue

Comment: That worked to get the selected record and then get the itemcode. However I could not get to work the overall process, edited the question for details.